# Internet Explorer task manager

Tags: internet-explorer, process, task-manager

If I open an Internet Explorer window, there are two entries created in the list of Processes under Windows Task Manager:

- iexplorer-10832
- iexplorer-5076

Why does the Windows Task Manager show two entries even when I've only opened a single Internet Explorer window?

Comment: I am not talking about tabs, I am referring to new IE windows

Answer (score 4):

Starting with IE 8, [tabs are run in a different, lower-privileged process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0).

Comment: No. I am not talking about tabs, I am referring to new IE windows.

Comment: @Muhammed, tabs and windows are the same thing. Windows are just free-floating tabs, and tabs are just windows strung together. The point is that all tabs and windows (ie, all individual pages/sites) are run as separate processes.